# Checking the number of digits in Scala

Tags: scala, require

I need to to check whether the number of digits in a number are equal to some other number. The best way I could come up with was this:

```
require(Number.toString  == """\d{8}""", throw new InvalidDateFormatException("Wrong format for string parameter"))
```

where the number of digits required are 8. Is there any better way?

Comment: `string == regex` will probably never evaluate to true because `==` doesn't evaluate the regex. Use `matches` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One alternative:

```
require(Number.toString.length == 8, throw new InvalidDateFormatException("Wrong format for string parameter"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another (academic) approach is to count the digits:

```
def digits(num: Int) = {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def run(num: Int, digits: Int): Int =
    if(num > 0) run(num / 10, digits + 1)
    else        digits

  run(math.abs(num), 0)
}
```

You could then, for example, use implicit conversions to add a `digits` method to existing numeric types.

I'll readily admit that this is overkill and more than likely premature optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be

```
require(Number > 9999999 && Number < 100000000,throw new InvalidDateFormatException("Wrong format for string parameter"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not terribly elegant, but avoid transformation to strings:

```
def check(num: Int, digits: Int) = {
  val div = math.pow(10, digits - 1)

  num < div * 10 && num > div - 1
}

println(check(12345678, 8)) // true
println(check(12345678, 9)) // false
println(check(12345678, 7)) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you the number of decimals

```
def countDecimals(d: Double): Int = (BigDecimal(d) - BigDecimal(d.toInt)).precision

countDecimals(10321.1234) == 4 // True
```

And if you want to get the full length of the number:

```
BigDecimal(d).precision

BigDecimal(10321.1234).precision == 9 // True
```

Comment: Not exactly sure how this `.precision` works. `BigDecimal(0.00034).precision` returns: `Int 2`